# How do I make a retry pop up if the input isn't what is wanted?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

So I am trying to make a JOptionPanel popup when a user doesn't put in a number from 0-60 in a JTextField, but I'm not sure how

Here is what I tried

```
else if(e.getSource() == Save) {

            Task task = new Task();
            task.hour = hin.getText();
            task.min = min.getText();
            if(min.getText() > 0 && min.getText() < 60) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid time.");
            }
            else{
            task.day = (String) dayspinner.getValue();
            task.description = desc.getText();
            tasks.add(task);
            ObjectOutputStream os = null;
            try{
                os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(save));
                os.writeObject(tasks);
                os.close();
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            tframe.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

But I get errors that say "bad operand types for binary operator'<'".

Comment: *"user .. put in a number from 0-60"*  [`.. new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(..));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#JSpinner-javax.swing.SpinnerModel-) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getText()` method returns a `String`, and you cannot use `<` or `>` to compare `String`s. It would be better if you convert the result of `min#getText` to an `int` first, then do the proper comparison. You can do this by using `Integer#parseInt()`:

```
int minVal = Integer.parseInt(min.getText());
//fixed the condition
if (!(minVal > 0 && minVal < 60)) {
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but now it gives me an error saying
"int cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: @DavidL that's strange. Probably you should use another name for the local variable.

Answer (score 2):

For user input validation, use either `JFormattedTextField`, `JSpinner`, `InputVerfifer` or even a `DocumentFilter` (but if you get here, there's something you're probably doing wrong)

These will allow you to validate the field's in real time (post focus change) and ensure that the user is only allowed to enter the values you want.  You can also use an `InputVerifier` to restrict a change of focus, so the user won't be able to leave the field until they have entered a valid value

See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`String` cant be compared using comparison-operators. Parse the `int`-value (`Integer.parseInt(String someString)`) instead and compare these.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    if(min.getText() > 0 && min.getText() < 60) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid time.");
    }
```

To

```
    if(Integer.parseInt(min.getText()) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(min.getText()) < 60) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid time.");
    }
```